# How can i generate minified CSS files in same directory with PostCSS

Tags: css, npm, minify, postcss, postcss-cli

I would like to use PostCSS to generate minified CSS files in a same directory with "min" keyword. I have various CSS files and each file should be minify and add a ".min" along with their file names. Following is the structure.

From the following:

```
assets/css/home.css
assets/css/about.css
assets/css/contact.css
```

To the following:

```
assets/css/home.min.css
assets/css/about.min.css
assets/css/contact.min.css
```

I tried the following NPM script but failed.

```
  "scripts": {
    "postcss": "postcss assets/css/*.css > assets/css/*.min.css -w"
  },
```

Hopes someone can help me. Thanks in Advance!